# JBoss behind NAT hostname problem

Tags: nat, jboss, hostname

My company has a JBoss cluster sitting behind a firewall that performs NAT. We forward ports to JBoss from the firewall, so that our client application can access the server. We are having trouble when JBoss replies it tells the clients to connect to the internal hostname, not the external one with which the initial connection was made.

Is this something that is easily resolved/configured?

How are other JBoss app servers configured behind NAT firewalls? Split-horizon DNS?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use apache as a reverse proxy with mod_jk; if you don't require a full reverse-proxy setup then it [looks like](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html#Proxy%20Support) you just have to set `proxyName` in tomcat's http connector at server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml.